# Extract many types of compressed files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, zip, compression, tar

I want extract any type of compressed file (`.tar.gz`, `.zip`,etc) in `nodejs`
Situation: A compressed file of any type comes from frontend and in want to extract it knowing it's type by finding it's extension, i can't able to find any package that can extract multiple types of compresses files, please give some suggestion or a package that can compress any compressed file by specifying it the file type.

Comment: There is no such module that can uncompress all the possible extensions. Better to ask from your client a specific list of extensions that he wants to support, and then use this list to check for modules.

Comment: you can check mime type and handle accordingly for those that you know how to decompress